# Create a grid where the grid items have a max-width but are still equally spaced across the device width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a (2 row - 3 column) grid with `1fr 1fr 1fr` spacing. Inside each grid item there is a `<img>` with a `max-width: 512px`. I gave the grid a `margin: 0 3.75rem`. Now I have the problem that the grid-items are bigger than the grid-item-content (512px). How can I make a grid so it has the same visual appearance like a flexbox with `justify-content: space-between;`? Is there a "gap: auto"- workaround?

what i have vs what i want:
[image: (picture) what I have vs what I want:]

this is what I have so far:

```css
#grid {
    margin: 0 3.75rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
    "1 2 3" auto
    "4 5 6" auto / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;

.gridItem {
    height: 56rem;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 512px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px dashed #cb34ed;

}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="1" class="gridItem"><div class="img"></div></div>
    <div id="2" class="gridItem"><div class="img"></div></div>
    <div id="3" class="gridItem"><div class="img"></div></div>
    <div id="4" class="gridItem"><div class="img"></div></div>
    <div id="5" class="gridItem"><div class="img"></div></div>
</div>
```

I know I could split them into 2 flexbox rows and give them `justify-content: space-between;` but I need it to be a grid! Can someone help? I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the functional notation of nth-child as explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Try setting:

- `justify-items: center;` on the grid itself
- `justify-self: start;` for every third grid item starting with the first item
- `justify-self: end;` for every third grid item starting with the third item

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-items: center;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.gridItem {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 10rem;
}

/* for every 3rd item starting with the first one */
.gridItem:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  justify-self: start;
}

/* for every 3rd item starting with the third one */
.gridItem:nth-child(3n+3) {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  justify-self: end;
}

.gridItem img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="1" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="2" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="3" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="4" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="5" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

If you are happy to use `auto` for your column widths instead of `1fr`, you can even use `justify-content: space-between;` just like you can with flexbox. This solution is nice and simple.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.gridItem {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 10rem;
}

.gridItem img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="1" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="2" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="3" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="4" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
    <div id="5" class="gridItem"><img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working on this for about 3h now :D

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to achieve this with 5 griditems in a row?

Comment: With five columns, the spacing wouldn't be correct using the first method, but it would be correct using the second method (auto column widths and space-between).